# Why does the definition of a fixed field specify a subgroup of the Galois group, not just a subset?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Why does the definition for the fixed field of $H$ specify that $H$ must be a **subgroup** of the Galois group of the field extension? As far as I can see, if $H$ is simply a **subset**, the 'fixed field' of $H$ is still a field, as we have closure under all $4$ operations.

So, am I missing something, or is the requirement for $H$ to be a subgroup not necessary for the fixed field of $H$ to actually be a field?

Comment: Could you please indicate where exactly this definition is given. That would help answer your question more fully.

Comment: The definition is in 'Galois Theory' by Ian Stewart, 4th edition, page 114-115 in the section about the Galois correspondence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a field is fixed by a subset $S$ of $G$, it is also fixed by the subgroup generated by $S$, so there is no loss of generality.

Comment: Did you mean to say "also fixed by the subgroup generated by that subset"? [instead of subgroup generated by $G$ which is just $G$ anyway.]

Comment: Thanks; fixed .

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! Certainly I can see why the field fixed by a subset is contained in the field fixed by the subgroup generated by that subset. But, are they necessarily equal? Ie is the fixed field of a subset the same as the fixed field of the subgroup generated by that subset?